# Flow does not run on Tableau Server - where can I see the actual error?

Tags: tableau-api

When I run a flow in Tableau Server, it fails with the following error message:

[image: Tableau Flow error on server]

Unfortunately this error is not helpful in understanding the actual cause of the problem.
Is there a way to see the actual underlying error? Or how am I supposed to debug this?
The flow runs fine in my Tableau Prep. 
(EDIT: I used state here that I used a different data source to test in prep, but this is no longer true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably that error log does give you a hint as to what the issue is. The issue is with the Output step. This is most likely due to a permissions error when Tableau Server goes to publish the output since you can do it locally in Tableau Prep.

Are credentials for your flows able to be embedded on server? This will impact whether the output will be accessible. Are all flows run using a service account? Make sure that service account has access to the output location.

If these troubleshooting steps don't work, check the server logs. For this you'll need to check the logs on Tableau Server using the command line to see if there is a more detailed response. If you have the access, run `tsm maintenance ziplogs` to zip the log files and investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dan.

About the permissions, I don't think that this is the issue here, as I am able to have a slightly different flow run with a similar output step.

I will ask a colleague that has access to the server to run that command and send me the log files, hopefully those will be helpful.

Comment: OK, I was able to find an error in the Tableau Server logs - some datetime fields are interpreted as strings for some reason. While I still don't understand why it happens, this is still quite a bit better then the generic error above, so I'll accept the answer.